# AWS CDK SFN JsonPath.stringAt to handle minus symbol

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a function written in Typescript in my CDK code:

```
export function getS3FileLocation(dirName: string) {
  return sfn.JsonPath.stringAt(`$.myS3Bucket.${dirName}[0].location`);
}
```

Not surprise, here is the generated Cloudformation code if I pass `my-dir` as `dirName`:

```
$.myS3Bucket.my-dir[0].location
```

However, due to the minus symbol `-`, Cloudformation throws exception

```
The value for the field 'MyField.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call at /States/My State/Parameters'
```

If I pass `my_dir` as `dirName`, the generated Cloudformation code would be `$.myS3Bucket.my_dir[0].location`, and Cloudformation does not throw exception.

How to handle the minus symbol `-`? For some reason, I have to pass `my-dir` as `dirName`.

The input payload is `{"myS3Bucket":{"my-dir":[{"location":"location-1"}]}}`

Comment: Can you confirm that your SFN payload actually contains a key with a dash in it?

Comment: @gshpychka Yes the payload is `{"myS3Bucket":{"my-dir":[{"location":"location-1"}]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using keys as a dictionary instead of "." might work.

$.myS3Bucket["my-dir"][0].location
$["myS3Bucket"]["my-dir"][0].location

Comment: Using keys as a dictionary works - `sfn.JsonPath.stringAt(`$.myS3Bucket['${dirName}'][0].location`)`, the generated CFN code is `$.myS3Bucket['my-dir'][0].location`